# Python 3: My code is suppose to print one name and one score from this file but its prints the name twice and the score twice. Why?

Tags: python

This is the assignment:

- The first program will read each player’s name and golf score as keyboard input, then save these as records in a file named golf.txt. (Each record will have a field for the player’s name and a field for the player’s score.)
- The second program reads the records from the golf.txt file and displays them.

This is my code so far:

```
def main():
    Continue = 'yes'
    golf_file = open('golf.txt', 'a')
    while Continue == 'yes':
        player_name = input("Input the player's name: ")
        player_score = input("Input the player's score: ")
        golf_file.write(player_name + "\n")
        golf_file.write(str(player_score) + "\n")
        Continue = input("Would you like to continue? [yes]: ")
    display_file = input("Would you like to display the records from the golf.txt? [yes]: ")
    golf_file.close()
    if(display_file == 'yes'):
            displayfile()

def displayfile():
    golf_file = open('golf.txt', 'r')

    for line in golf_file:
        print("The score of this person is: ",line)
        print("The name of this person is: ",line)
    golf_file.close()

main()
```

When the names/scores print it looks like this:
[image]

The golf.txt:
[image]

Comment: so whats the issue??

Comment: You read a line and print it twice. You need to read two lines at a time since you wrote name and score on separate lines, or write them on the same line with a separator

Comment: How is your golf.txt file written exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading one line (that contains the name), and printing it as the name *and* the score. Then you read the next line containing a score) and print it as the name and the score again.

You want to *alternate* treating a line as a name or a score, something like

```
def displayfile():
    with open('golf.txt', 'r') as golf_file:

        for name in golf_file:
            print("The name of this person is: ", name)
            score = next(golf_file)
            print("The score of this person is: ", score)
```

Because `golf_file` is its own iterator, calling `next` in the body of the loop advances the file pointer by one line, so that the loop always resumes by reading a name line.

Something a little more symmetric might be

```
def displayfile():
    with open('golf.txt', 'r') as golf_file:
        while True:
            try:
                name = next(golf_file)
                score = next(golf_file)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            print("The name of this person is: ", name)
            print("The score of this person is: ", score)
```

Even simpler, though, would be to write each name and score on a single line.

```
def main():
    with open('golf.txt', 'a') as golf_file:
        while True:
            player_name = input("Input the player's name: ")
            player_score = input("Input the player's score: ")
            golf_file.write(f"{player_name}\t{player_score}\n")

            continue = input("Would you like to continue? [yes]: ")
            if continue != 'yes':
               break
    display_file = input("Would you like to display the records from the golf.txt? [yes]: ")
    if display_file == 'yes':
        displayfile()


def displayfile():
    with open('golf.txt', 'r') as golf_file:

        for line in golf_file:
            name, score = line.strip().split('\t')
            print("The score of this person is: ", name)
            print("The name of this person is: ", score)

main()
```